# extjs 3.2 add vertical scrollbar dynamically

Tags: extjs, extjs3

2,I am displaying more than 15 records in gridpanel . But only 10 records are displaying, other records are hiding below. I want to add vertical scrollbar to gridpanel, how can i achieve this.

Comment: Show some code so we can understand where you getting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `autoScroll : true` config

OR

give `overflow:auto` css property to body of grid